# Child textbox will not stretch when grid in ListBox ItemTemplate is split into two columns

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to have a `Grid` with two columns in a ListBox's ItemTemplate, splitting it in half. I also want to have two `TextBox` controls in the grid that stretch fully. I am currently using the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" InputScope="Text" Text="{Binding Key, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" InputScope="Text" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Fortunately, it looks like the columns split the grid in half. Unfortunately, it looks like the two `TextBox` controls don't stretch to use all the available horizontal space. Here's an image:

[image: How the previous XAML turns out]

If I put enough text in the textboxes, they stretch to fill all available horizontal space evenly. The problem is that they're not stretching when the text isn't in the `TextBox` controls.

I've tried removing the column definitions and setting both of the `TextBox` controls' widths to `*` and `.5*`, but that results in some exception of type `System.Exception` to be thrown before the page renders. I've also tried setting the column definitions' `MinWidth` property to `*` and `.5*`, but that also causes the same type of exception to be thrown.

How can I properly make the columns take 50% of the available width and the controls inside it to stretch accordingly?

Comment: You have to give width of any of the column because how 2nd column will know about the width of 1st and vice versa.

Comment: @Dragon Is there another way to split the columns up without specifying one of the column's width? Is it absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing inside the code in the initialize part you can specify both column width as `Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.Width/2` and to both of them so your problem will be solved.

Comment: I guess this could work, but I was hoping for a solution using only XAML... :/

Comment: Thotough xaml you can only have a static or you can give minwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I found another soultion that works in XAML! Simply put this under your ListBox tag:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```